# What is meant by the speed of light in a vacuum if a true vacuum cannot exist?

Tags: speed-of-light, vacuum

Because of quantum mechanics doesn't allow for a perfect vacuum, what does it mean to say the speed of light in something that cannot exist is a constant?

Comment: Quantum field theory has a vacuum state. The theory wouldn’t make sense without it. The fact that you may not consider it “true” or “perfect” is not relevant.

Comment: Hello Greg Sternberg and welcome to Physics SE. I strongly suggest to support your sayings with some evidence, whether this is a scientific article, cites from some textbook, your own work (at least when it is not proprietary) or even some website blog. It doesn't necessarily has to be something peer-reviewed or considered to be of very high impact, as erroneous sources **can** be disproved, which is another form of knowledge dissemination.

Comment: The speed of light is not measurably impacted by the self-interaction of the physical vacuum. At low energies the vacuum is, for all we know, asymptotically "free". There may be another phase transition at extremely low energies, but that is experimentally simply not reachable, so we neglect it.

Comment: Greg, welcome to the makebelieve world of Academic Physics... As you said a true vacuum is not possible, so how can one measure a speed of light in vacuum?1 A connundrum...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Ghoster, this is fair and perhaps semantic -- what do we mean by a vaccum?  FlatterMann, thank you.  This is helpful.  MathematicalPhysicist, after reading the replies, I don't think it's a connundrum as much as a matter of how one defines a vaccum.

Comment: *what do we mean by a vaccum* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vacuum_state Please note that “vacuum” is spelled with one “c” and two “u”s; it is not “vaccum”. Also: Many members of this site would take issue with some of the “popular science” language in the Wikipedia article, such as virtual particles “popping in and out” of existence. The vacuum state does not actually change with time, so this language gives a false impression.

Answer (score 1):

In what follows, I'm glossing over detailed mathematical justifications, to give a very loose description (which I gauge to be the level of the question).

Let's think of what can bubble out of the quantum vacuum: either photons or other charged particles. Photons cannot (directly) interact with other photons, but they can interact with other charged particles, and the strength of interaction "renormalizes" the fine structure constant (basically, the strength of the electromagnetic interaction). It turns out that even after such renormalization, the mass of the photon is still zero (could think of this as a consequence of gauge invariance) and therefore photons still propagate at the maximum allowed speed (the so called speed of light).

Comment: Thank you Siva, this was a very nice and helpful reply!  I think I have a better understanding now -- the term vaccum isn't so important.  What's important is how the photons interact with the medium and if after all of those interactions are taken into account, the mass of the photon is zero, then the only speed they can travel at is c.  Are there other interactions that photons have such that after renormalization, one comes up with a non-zero mass?

Comment: There can be many interactions, but the constraint of gauge invariance prevents a photon mass from being generated.

Comment: Thanks again Siva!

Answer (score 0):

As long, as light does not interact with any material it has the vacuum light speed. So light from the stars coming to us has lightspeed, if it encounters matter it does not reach us directly.

Comment: Thanks trula,  this is helpful.  So my takeaway is that the term vaccum really refers to any propgation path that does not interact with other particles.  So a vaccum need not be perfect, rather it needs to be filled with particles that very rarely ever interact with the photons moving through space.